# System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedFault causing SerializationException in IIS hosted WCF call

Tags: asp.net, wcf, exception, iis

I've got a service call in an IIS hosted WCF service that is calling into another WCF service in the same IIS instance through HTTP.  Normally, if the second service returns a FaultException, this is forwarded on to the caller of the first service.  Just recently, however, the iis service is occasionally shutting down after receiving a serialization exception.

```
Type 'System.ServiceModel.Channels.ReceivedFault' in Assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(System.RuntimeType)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(System.Type, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(System.Object, System.Runtime.Serialization.ISurrogateSelector, System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerObjectInfoInit, System.Runtime.Serialization.IFormatterConverter, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationBinder)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.NameInfo)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(System.Object, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[], System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryWriter, Boolean)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(System.IO.Stream, System.Object, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[], Boolean)
    System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.SerializeObject(System.Object, System.IO.MemoryStream)
    System.AppDomain.Serialize(System.Object) 
   System.AppDomain.MarshalObject(System.Object)
```

The IIS application only has a single appdomain, so I'm not sure where this CrossAppDomainSerializer is coming into play.

Comment: Your both WCF service are running in different appdomain and not in same one.

Comment: I considered that the WCF services might communicate through remoting if they are hosted in the same IIS instance, but this FaultException is a fairly standard occurence and it doesn't usually cause the serialization exception.

Comment: Thanks.  I went back and using this information was able to replicate the exception locally by splitting it into separate application pools.  Still not sure what to do with this information, but if you make that an answer I will mark it correct.